# How do I prevent the color of the link from turning blue when clicked?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

im use tailwind css in next js.

```
<a href="#" className="active:bg-none  hover:bg-transparent focus:bg-transparent visited:bg-transparent">link</a>
```

and even in css i've added this

`a:focus, a:active, a:visited {border: none; outline: none; text-decoration: none; background-color: transparent; background: transparent; }`

Comment: if is not work, try to add `!important` sometimes is there a bug. also however in the CSS code you wrote I don't see any `color` CSS property. the thing in CSS that link become blue isn't the background, but the color. maybe try resetting the color property.

Comment: it's the default color property that causes the visual change. Just use the `color` property and set it to a fixed value.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following css rule:

```
a {
    color: rgb(0, 102, 204);
}
```